# VBA - Class property with reserved keyword as the name

Tags: vba

In VBA, is there any known mechanism to fool the compiler into allowing the use of reserved keywords as names for class properties?  For example, I would like to create a property called `Select` in one of my class modules.  However, the compiler flags my declaration as an error.  Below is the syntax I used:

```
Public Property Get Select() As Database.SQLStatements

End Property
```

`Database` is my VBA project name and `SQLStatements` is one of the class modules I created.  Also, I'm running the code in MS Access 2010.

Comment: The search you want is "vba use reserved word as identifier", which gives [Access 2007 reserved words and symbols](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe), which says surround the identifier with square brackets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that and use any keyword/reserved word in your VBA. But then it will make your code a lot messy and very hard to read/debug/maintain.

If you have a bool property named `If` in your class you will end up with something like this  `If .If  Then`, well, good luck reading that. Also code maintenance like Find/Replace/rename etc. will need extra caution and more work.

---

Anyhow, if you are willing to go through all this pain, here is how you do it. 
**After the keywords/reserved words add a invisible blank space using ALT+0160**  and that's it. VBA will consider it a perfectly legal name. e.g. `If` .

Also, you will have to either use intellisense for using these propertynames or manually type the altcode everywhere. That's extra typing.

---

clsTest

```
Option Explicit

Private m_sSelect   As String
Private m_bIF       As Boolean

Public Property Get Select () As String '~~> Select () is actually typed as SelectALT+0160()
    Select  = m_sSelect
End Property

Public Property Let Select (ByVal sNewValue As String)
    m_sSelect = sNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get If () As Boolean
    If  = m_bIF
End Property

Public Property Let If (ByVal bNewValue As Boolean)
    m_bIF = bNewValue
End Property
```

---

Test Module

```
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

    Dim objTestClass As clsTest

    Set objTestClass = New clsTest

    With objTestClass
        .Select  = "It works. But it will, for sure, create readibility/maintenance issues."
        .If  = False
    End With

    MsgBox objTestClass.Select 

    '/ See how hard it will to read/debug this sort of code

     With objTestClass
        If .If  Then '~~> This line here  :)
            MsgBox "If prop value is TRUE"
        Else
            MsgBox "If prop value is FALSE"
        End If
     End With

End Sub
```

---

*ALT+0160 <> Space*

Comment: Thank you for giving me a good workaround.  I'm not too keen on the extra space but it absolutely does work and I've learned something new.

Comment: ++ as always out of box thinking.